# Batch Size Calculation Array, Quotient, Sequence

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out a formula for calculating optimal batch sizes for production.

N = material reguired in (KG)

X = minimum 45(KG) required on the machine for processing

Y = maximum 100(KG) required on the machine for processing

If N = 90, I will use a batch size of 2 at 45KG.

If N=100, I will use a batch size of 1 at 60KG.

I have used =CEILING(N,X/X) which yields the batch sizes at 45.
I have used =CEILING(N,Y/Y) which yields the batch sizes at 100.

However, I would need to use a range of numbers for 45~100 (X:Y) such as =CEILING(N,X:Y/X:Y) in order to find the most optimal batch size to be used on the machine with N qty. [Current sheet example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDoAF.png)

Comment: 1. What do you call "optimal"? 2. Why would you use a batch size of 2 at 45 KG for N = 90, why not 1 at 90 KG? 3. Why would you use a batch size of 1 at 60 KG for N = 100, why not 1 at 100 KG, where did 60 come from?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: And in your photo example, batch size 100, where does the residual of 10 come from?